# How to export SQLite database tables into csv files in Android

Tags: android, export-to-csv

I want to export my SQLite database tables in to .csv file. When I am exporting the database, it exports successfully all records will be shown in my mobile phone perfectly,  but the problem is when I copy that .csv file from my mobile to my computer some data get lost. The .csv file does not increases its size as per the data. What is the problem ? My code is as follows:-

```
File  outFile = new File(DATABASE_DIRECTORY, outFileName);
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        Cursor cursor = controller.getInfo();

    //  int col_count = cursor.getColumnCount();


        csvHeader += "" + "id" + ",";
        csvHeader += "" + "name" + ",";
        csvHeader += "" + "class" + ",";
        csvHeader += "" + "div" + "";
        csvHeader += "\r\n";

        if (cursor != null) {
            out.write(csvHeader);
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                csvValues = cursor.getString(0) + ","; 
                csvValues += cursor.getString(1) + ","; 
                csvValues += cursor.getString(2) + ","; 
                csvValues += cursor.getString(3) + ","; 

                out.write(csvValues);


                cursor.moveToNext();
            }


        }

        out.close();
        cursor.close();
        returnCode = true;
```

Comment: Are you saying that locally the exported file is fully readable and when copying it to your pc, it's kind of damaged?

Comment: yes exactly....  when I open the exported csv file in mobile it shows all entries but when I copy that file from my mobile to computer some data losts...

Comment: that's very unlikely. sounds more like you are copying the wrong file